# How to prove geometrically the difference between line and plane?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Explain geometrically why $(x,y,z) = (1,9,17) + s(1,1,1) + t(-2,-2,-2)$ represents the equation of a line and not a plane.

EDIT: the extension to this question asks "based on the above answer, does the equation (x,y,z) = (2,1,1) +s(-1,-1,-1) + t(2,-2,-2) represent a line or plane? I claimed it is a plane, as now the two direction vectors are not multiples and thus for any values of s and t, we can get infinite points on the plane. Is this true?

Comment: What do $s$ and $t$ represent?

Comment: s and t are simply the unknown parametric for their corresponding direction vectors. This question confuses me as a line can have one parametric, however a plane has two and they CAN be parallel. Thus I keep thinking this is infact a plane.

Comment: Now that's the proper form of the question. I have to prove this geometrically as opposed to with algebra.

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: Geometrically you go to point $(1,9,17)$ and you move only in one direction $(1,1,1),$ since $(-2,-2,-2)=-2(1,1,1)$ gives the same direction. So, if you start from a point and move along one direction you get a line and not a plane.

Comment: As of yet i've noticed that the direction vectors are multiples of each other, and so I believe that they are the same line with a common point. As opposed to two separate parallel lines on the same plane.

Answer (score 2):

The vectors for $t$ and $s$ are parallel to each other and any linear combination is still parallel. You only have one direction and can only reach points on a line, as the vectors have a common origin.

---

Using this type of equation $\vec p=\vec p_0+s\vec u+t\vec v$, $t=0$ and $t=1$ define two parallel lines of the plane, $\vec p=\vec p_0+s\vec u$ and $\vec p=\vec p_0+s\vec u+\vec v$.

Comment: So the two parallel lines essentially represent one line that goes through point (1,9,17)? What would this look like if it was a plane, as I believe a plane can have to parallel lines?

Comment: @SaadSiddiqui: see my addition.

Answer (score 0):

Because (1,1,1) and (-2,-2,-2) are dedendent.

THe equation is the same as $(x,y,z) = (1,9,17) + (s - 2t)(1,1,1) = (1,9,17) + t'(1,1,1)$ where $t' = s - 2t$

which is a line

Comment: Makes sense, thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

The vectors $(1, 1, 1)$ and $(-2, -2, -2)$ are colinar, because $(-2, -2, -2) = -2 (1, 1, 1)$ and so the equation can be rewritten using only one parameter:

$(x, y, z) = (1, 9, 17) + (s -2 s) (1, 1, 1) = (1, 9, 17) + k (1, 1, 1)$

So it is one dimensional, i.e. a line.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Drawn on an xyz grid, could they represent the same line?